# Add a column in gridview at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to add a new column in grid view at run time and in this column I want to add a button in some specific rows. How can I do this?
Please suggest me some relevant solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you please add your existing code to show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can programmatically add column fields to the Columns collection, it is easier to list the column fields declaratively in the GridView control and then use the **Visible** property of each column field to show or hide each column field.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So you see what you should do is go ahead and create the column in your GridView, but **set the Visible property to False**. Then to control the display of the column, you can make use of the **GridView.RowDataBound Event**.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You should also be able to handle displaying a button from within the same RowDataBound handler.

```
 void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
           if(condition)
           {
                Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ButtonID");
                btn.Visible = false;
           }
      }
 }
```